# Function parameter undefined inside ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I already checked other questions but I didn't solve this issue.

Here is my entire code: http://codepen.io/tiuscia/pen/qqLQNd

I have a function inside the controller that I call without parameter for the input text and with parameter for the recent links.

These links are inside a ng-repeat and they call a function using ng-click:

HTML

```
 <h3>Search History:</h3>

 <div ng-repeat="city in meteo.cityList" >
     <a ng-click="meteo.search(city)"  href="#">{{city}}</a>
 </div>
```

When I click the links the function is called but no parameter is passed.
I'm not using $scope.

Could you please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First off, it works for me (Chrome 55)... I did a `console.log(input)` in your search function and I saw it was returned when I clicked on a search history item.

Second, the syntax you are using for setting default search parameters is ES6 and may not be supported across browsers (that is if you aren't doing some sort of downward transpiling which I will assume you aren't).

I would instead assign your default function parameter like this:

```
$scope.search = function(input) {
  input = (typeof input !== 'undefined') ?  input : self.city;
  // ...
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Or if you want to see the ng-click with parameters in action, check out this demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/BzazAa?p=preview

Comment: great advice. I tried console.log(input) and actually the input variable is correct, but the function still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

define the function using $scope if you can:

Then have the function defined like this

$scope.search= function (city) {

};

Note how I just gave a name inside the () and nothing else, that should work